# Android Studio: How do I re-include an excluded library from auto-complete?

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete, ide

So I've recently excluded `java.text` from my auto-complete feature by right-clicking on it and then pressing the "remove from code-completion" function. How do I include it back?

Comment: Should be in the code completion tab. Tools -> Code completion -> something like removed libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import**.

There is a exclusions box over there from where you can remove the library you wish to re-appear in code completion.

[image]

Comment: In newer versions of Android Studio, this is located in a slightly different location.

Go to Android Studio -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import.